# Kernel Panic on reboot

Tags: rhel, kernel, kernel-panic, panic

I manage a RHEL 8.2 server hosted in Azure and whenever I reboot the server, it goes to Kernel Panic. I am getting the below error message.

```
    Starting Reboot...
        [1892395.172835] printk: systemd-shutdow: 45 output lines suppressed due to ratelimiting
        [1892395.182765] systemd-shutdown[1]: Syncing filesystems and block devices.
        [1892395.200269] systemd-shutdown[1]: Sending SIGTERM to remaining processes...
        [1892395.207060] systemd-journald[742]: Received SIGTERM from PID 1 (systemd-shutdow).
[1892395.227451] systemd-shutdown[1]: Sending SIGKILL to remaining processes...
[1892395.237894] systemd-shutdown[1]: Unmounting file systems.
[1892395.242465] [2350545]: Remounting '/var' read-only in with options '(null)'.
[1892395.281287] EXT4-fs (dm-4): re-mounted. Opts: (null)
[1892395.297105] [2350546]: Unmounting '/var'.
[1892395.371209] [2350547]: Remounting '/storage' read-only in with options 'attr2,inode64,noquota'.
[1892395.740647] [2350548]: Unmounting '/storage'.
[1892396.026064] XFS (sda2): Unmounting Filesystem
[1892396.100906] [2350549]: Remounting '/usr' read-only in with options '(null)'.
[1892396.184728] EXT4-fs (dm-1): re-mounted. Opts: (null)
[1892396.210664] [2350550]: Remounting '/' read-only in with options '(null)'.
[1892396.231700] EXT4-fs (dm-5): re-mounted. Opts: (null)
[1892396.236991] systemd-shutdown[1]: All filesystems unmounted.
[1892396.241123] systemd-shutdown[1]: Deactivating swaps.
[1892396.244523] systemd-shutdown[1]: All swaps deactivated.
[1892396.249026] systemd-shutdown[1]: Detaching loop devices.
[1892396.252787] systemd-shutdown[1]: All loop devices detached.
[1892396.256663] systemd-shutdown[1]: Detaching DM devices.
[1892396.313043] printk: shutdown: 14 output lines suppressed due to ratelimiting
[1892396.357695] dracut Warning: Killing all remaining processes
dracut Warning: Killing all remaining processes
[1892396.975761] dracut Warning: Unmounted /oldroot/usr.
[1892396.992162] BUG: unable to handle kernel paging request at 00007770000069a8
[1892396.993004] PGD 0 P4D 0 
[1892396.993004] Oops: 0000 [#1] SMP PTI
[1892396.993004] CPU: 0 PID: 2350587 Comm: umount Not tainted 4.18.0-193.6.3.el8_2.x86_64 #1
[1892396.993004] Hardware name: Microsoft Corporation Virtual Machine/Virtual Machine, BIOS 090007  06/02/2017
[1892396.993004] RIP: 0010:__list_del_entry_valid+0x2d/0x4c
[1892396.993004] Code: 48 8b 57 08 48 b9 00 01 00 00 00 00 ad de 48 39 c8 0f 84 5a 00 00 00 48 b9 00 02 00 00 00 00 ad de 48 39 ca 0f 84 7d 00 00 00 <48> 8b 32 48 39 fe 0f 85 5d 00 00 00 48 8b 50 08 48 39 f2 0f 85 42
[1892396.993004] RSP: 0018:ffff9b58c3f3bd90 EFLAGS: 00010203
[1892396.993004] RAX: 0000000000002028 RBX: ffff8c0f9333f000 RCX: dead000000000200
[1892396.993004] RDX: 00007770000069a8 RSI: ffff8c0f9e6be400 RDI: ffff8c0f9333ecc0
[1892396.993004] RBP: ffff8c0f97a85150 R08: 0000000000000000 R09: 0000000000000000
[1892396.993004] R10: ffff9b58c3f3be18 R11: 0000000000000000 R12: ffff8c0f9333ecc0
[1892396.993004] R13: ffff8c0f980df8c0 R14: 0000000000000000 R15: ffffffffab0b5530
[1892396.993004] FS:  00007f9485309080(0000) GS:ffff8c0f9dc00000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
[1892396.993004] CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
[1892396.993004] CR2: 00007770000069a8 CR3: 0000000874618005 CR4: 00000000003606f0
[1892396.993004] DR0: 0000000000000000 DR1: 0000000000000000 DR2: 0000000000000000
[1892396.993004] DR3: 0000000000000000 DR6: 00000000fffe0ff0 DR7: 0000000000000400
[1892396.993004] Call Trace:
[1892396.993004]  audit_tree_freeing_mark+0x148/0x2d0
[1892396.993004]  fsnotify_destroy_marks+0x6b/0xe0
[1892396.993004]  fsnotify_unmount_inodes+0xab/0x1a0
[1892396.993004]  ? __dentry_kill+0x121/0x170
[1892396.993004]  ? _cond_resched+0x15/0x30
[1892396.993004]  ? dentry_kill+0x4d/0x190
[1892396.993004]  generic_shutdown_super+0x32/0x100
[1892396.993004]  kill_block_super+0x21/0x50
[1892396.993004]  deactivate_locked_super+0x34/0x70
[1892396.993004]  cleanup_mnt+0x3b/0x70
[1892396.993004]  task_work_run+0x8a/0xb0
[1892396.993004]  exit_to_usermode_loop+0xeb/0xf0
[1892396.993004]  do_syscall_64+0x198/0x1a0
[1892396.993004]  entry_SYSCALL_64_after_hwframe+0x65/0xca
[1892396.993004] RIP: 0033:0x7f948433aebb
[1892396.993004] Code: ff 2b 00 f7 d8 64 89 01 48 83 c8 ff c3 66 90 f3 0f 1e fa 31 f6 e9 05 00 00 00 0f 1f 44 00 00 f3 0f 1e fa b8 a6 00 00 00 0f 05 <48> 3d 01 f0 ff ff 73 01 c3 48 8b 0d 9d ff 2b 00 f7 d8 64 89 01 48
[1892396.993004] RSP: 002b:00007ffd36c12a48 EFLAGS: 00000246 ORIG_RAX: 00000000000000a6
[1892396.993004] RAX: 0000000000000000 RBX: 000055b28656e970 RCX: 00007f948433aebb
[1892396.993004] RDX: 0000000000000001 RSI: 0000000000000000 RDI: 000055b28656eb50
[1892396.993004] RBP: 0000000000000000 R08: 000055b28656eb70 R09: 00007f94843bcc80
[1892396.993004] R10: 0000000000000000 R11: 0000000000000246 R12: 000055b28656eb50
[1892396.993004] R13: 00007f94850e7184 R14: 0000000000000000 R15: 00000000ffffffff
[1892396.993004] Modules linked in: vfat msdos fat ccm arc4 libarc4 md4 sha512_ssse3 sha512_generic cmac nls_utf8 cifs dns_resolver overlay nf_conntrack_ipv4 nf_defrag_ipv4 nft_counter xt_owner xt_conntrack nf_conntrack nft_compat fuse nf_tables nfnetlink binfmt_misc xfs libcrc32c intel_rapl_msr intel_rapl_common sb_edac kvm_intel kvm irqbypass crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel intel_rapl_perf hv_balloon hv_utils hyperv_fb i2c_piix4 joydev pcspkr auth_rpcgss sunrpc ip_tables ext4 mbcache jbd2 ata_generic sd_mod sg hv_storvsc hv_netvsc hyperv_keyboard scsi_transport_fc hid_hyperv ata_piix libata crc32c_intel hv_vmbus serio_raw dm_mirror dm_region_hash dm_log dm_mod
[1892396.993004] CR2: 00007770000069a8
[1892396.993004] ---[ end trace fe4fc9dab223a18d ]---
[1892396.993004] RIP: 0010:__list_del_entry_valid+0x2d/0x4c
[1892396.993004] Code: 48 8b 57 08 48 b9 00 01 00 00 00 00 ad de 48 39 c8 0f 84 5a 00 00 00 48 b9 00 02 00 00 00 00 ad de 48 39 ca 0f 84 7d 00 00 00 <48> 8b 32 48 39 fe 0f 85 5d 00 00 00 48 8b 50 08 48 39 f2 0f 85 42
[1892396.993004] RSP: 0018:ffff9b58c3f3bd90 EFLAGS: 00010203
[1892396.993004] RAX: 0000000000002028 RBX: ffff8c0f9333f000 RCX: dead000000000200
[1892396.993004] RDX: 00007770000069a8 RSI: ffff8c0f9e6be400 RDI: ffff8c0f9333ecc0
[1892396.993004] RBP: ffff8c0f97a85150 R08: 0000000000000000 R09: 0000000000000000
[1892396.993004] R10: ffff9b58c3f3be18 R11: 0000000000000000 R12: ffff8c0f9333ecc0
[1892396.993004] R13: ffff8c0f980df8c0 R14: 0000000000000000 R15: ffffffffab0b5530
[1892396.993004] FS:  00007f9485309080(0000) GS:ffff8c0f9dc00000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
[1892396.993004] CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
[1892396.993004] CR2: 00007770000069a8 CR3: 0000000874618005 CR4: 00000000003606f0
[1892396.993004] DR0: 0000000000000000 DR1: 0000000000000000 DR2: 0000000000000000
[1892396.993004] DR3: 0000000000000000 DR6: 00000000fffe0ff0 DR7: 0000000000000400
[1892396.993004] Kernel panic - not syncing: Fatal exception
[1892396.993004] Kernel Offset: 0x28e00000 from 0xffffffff81000000 (relocation range: 0xffffffff80000000-0xffffffffbfffffff)
[1892396.993004] ---[ end Kernel panic - not syncing: Fatal exception ]---
[H[J[1;1H[?25l[m[H[J[1;1H[20;7H[mUse the ^ and v keys to change the selection.
```

Looks like the below is the cause for panic

```
[1892396.357695] dracut Warning: Killing all remaining processes
dracut Warning: Killing all remaining processes
[1892396.975761] dracut Warning: Unmounted /oldroot/usr.
[1892396.992162] BUG: unable to handle kernel paging request at 00007770000069a8
[1892396.993004] PGD 0 P4D 0 
[1892396.993004] Oops: 0000 [#1] SMP PTI
[1892396.993004] CPU: 0 PID: 2350587 Comm: umount Not tainted 4.18.0-193.6.3.el8_2.x86_64 #1
[1892396.993004] Hardware name: Microsoft Corporation Virtual Machine/Virtual Machine, BIOS 090007  06/02/2017
[1892396.993004] RIP: 0010:__list_del_entry_valid+0x2d/0x4c
```

Please help me to fix this.

Thank you.